# Is there a formula that allows you calculate the n-th decimal digit of pi without calculating the previous digits?

Tags: pi, decimal-expansion

I know that there is a formula that allows one to calculate the n-th hexadecimal digit of pi without calculating the previous digits. But is there an analogous formula for decimal digits? I conjecture that there isn't. However, to rigorously prove that there isn't, one needs to define what a "formula" is. Has anyone rigorously done this, and either given an explicit formula, or proven that there isn't one?

Comment: Why would you conjecture that there isn't... Just "on general principles"? Or do you have some specific obstruction in mind? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few months ago Plouffe find a formula for obtaining the $n$-th digit of $\pi$ in base $10$:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12601

Comment: I think their method is just calculating pi to the precision of 10^-n, and their formula is just position(n, x)=[10{10^n x}].

Comment: @Lapin Yes, but the point of the article is giving an explicit formula for an approximation of $\pi$ that is good enough (with a precision higher of $10^{-n}$).

Comment: I think their method is not a method that gives the $n$th position without calculating the previous ones, so it is not what this question wants. When calculating the $n$th position, we have to calculate everything before it.